# Elastic search SQL display difference in data from last month

Tags: sql, database, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to build a query on Elastic, using ES SQL query syntax on Canvas, using the data table.

I want to display what was found (colour) in last month, that wasn’t found (colour) in this month. I am having trouble in the syntax in terms of getting the data between those 2 time frames. I want to see the difference of the colours compared to last month and this month.

Currently, this is what I have but it is not working:

`SELECT colour_name AS Colour, COUNT(colour_name) AS Total FROM “data” WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND NOT (timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOURS) GROUP BY Colour ORDER BY Total DESC`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please define "not working" an error? incorrect data?

Comment: Incorrect data :(